# I want to receive RTSP stream in OpenCV from web URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, video-streaming, webclient

I have RTSP url, when i play it using VLC it works. But i need to get the frames from stream in python. so i used OpenCv but it is not receiving the frame.

I need suggestion to solve this problem.
current code in Python Opencv is.

```
import os
import cv2
import sys


vcap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.")
while(1):
    ret, frame = vcap.read()
    if ret == 1:
        cv2.imshow('VIDEO', frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961318/read-frames-from-rtsp-stream-in-python/21052684

Comment: I have solved this using the same code. But with different RTSP URL.