# How to get current frame of RTSP using C /C++language?

Tags: c++, c, opencv, rtsp, libvlc

How to get current frame of RTSP using C /C++language?

I know there is many Python solution:
[Read Frames from RTSP Stream in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961318/read-frames-from-rtsp-stream-in-python)

If we can not use command (such as ffmpeg ..), just using c/c++ code.

I am try libvlc or openCV. How can I do? Thank you.

Comment: Consider using the gstreamer library

Comment: RTSP frame? That sounds entirely wrong. RTSP is the stream control protocol. It contains high-level commands like `PLAY rtsp://example.com/media.mp4 RTSP/1.0`. It doesn't bother with individual frames at all. RTSP isn't even video-specific. What would a "frame" even be when playing audio? Audio might have 44100 _samples_ per second.

Answer (score 0):

Use `libvlc_video_set_callbacks()` for libvlc 3.x.

There is another, faster, API in libvlc 4.x which uses the GPU.

Docs: https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__media__player.html#ga612605f2e5c638d9f4ed59021d714bf0